# Grails - Add a parameter to the params map

Tags: data-binding, grails, binding, parameters

I would like to add a single parameter to my `params` map, and bind the rest in a link. At the moment, I only bind the `params` classically as follows:

```
<g:link class="email" controller="administrator" action="test" params="${params}">Link text</g:link>
```

How could I add a parameter to the `params` map ?

Thank you in advance for you help.
Regards,

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have find a way to do it.

```
params="${params + ['forwardURI': request.forwardURI]}"
```

I do not know if there is any more Grails-like way to do it. If there is one, I would be obliged to learn it ;)

Comment: You might want to change the text of your link, as that is fairly inappropriate.  On topic, at what point are you trying to bind the data?

Comment: Hi Joseph, 
I would remove the tag if you insist but, working that way with 'params' maps, wouldn't you call that databinding ?

Comment: BTW Burt, I think I find 'I beat my wife' way more offensive :) But your choice :)

Comment: :) '13 characters to get my smiley accepted'

Comment: silly me, I was trying to do this, params="${params.put('forwardURI' ,request.forwardURI)}"  Didn't realize that there is a different way to do it in GSP

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do this repeatedly, you could use the answer you've posted in a `g:link` wrapper Tag Library, as Tag Libraries have access to `params` and `request`.

```
def forwardAwareLink = { attr, body ->
    attr.params = params + ['forwardURI': request.forwardURI]
    out << g.link(attr, body)
}
```

And in the gsp:

```
<g:forwardAwareLink class="email" controller="administrator" action="test">Link text</g:forwardAwareLink>
```

If you want to use the tag with your own custom parameter map from the gsp, you can also use the following in the Tag Library:

```
attr.params = attr.params + ['forwardURI': request.forwardURI]
```